# Captcha not working in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, captcha

hey guys,
i have downloaded mondor's captcha control, and implemented on localhost, thats working fine, but when i did the same steps and uploaded to the hosting server, i am unabel to get captcha image,i want to know whats the difference between placing dll's in bin folder and adding it as a reference because anyway it will go in bin folder. on localhost i added a reference to that dll and on hosting server i just added the dll in the bin folder, is that the problem, if yes than what could be the solution for this issue...

If anyone knows about it, please suggest..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check IIS version on server.
For IIS 7 
change the following line in `web.config file`  under `<system.webServer> <handlers>`:

```
<add name="MSCaptcha" path="CaptchaImage.axd" verb="GET" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check all folders and files had been uploaded related to captcha control